# How to use InstallShield LE2013 upgrade/overwrite the last version?

Tags: installshield

I want to use InstallShield LE2013 to create a setup package, and if user chooses the same path in setup, overwrite all files. How to do it?

I've read many answers about `ProductCode` / `Upgradecode`, but I didn't find any useful answer.

If I increase `ProductCode`, files will not overwritten and you will see two versions in Windows install/uninstall panel. If I increase `UpgradeCode`, it will show that I've setup the same software and tell me whether uninstall it or not. I don't want to uninstall it by user. Please give some advise.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the 'files and folders view', and select the files you would like to overwrite, and right click to bring up the "Properties" window, in there, check the box say 'always overwrite'.

Comment: thank you, joe, but the `Advanced` tag is unavailable in LE, it's set as default : windows installer versioning rules

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you're working on basic MSI project.
It seems like your environment or installer project is not working properly. Try cloning original repository in clean environment.

Only ProductCode and ProductVersion need to be updated. Keep UpgradeCode same as before. This should handle the scenario based on the [file versioning rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/file-versioning-rules).